# Stop streaming of background of div

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, background

I use a Video mjpeg as a background for a div:

url("http://192.168.201.115/cgi-bin/faststream.jpg?stream=Full&fps=0") 0% 0% / cover

The problem now is, if I remove the node from dom, or change the background to 'none' the image is still streaming

div:

```
    <div id="textDiv" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background: url(&quot;http://192.168.201.116/cgi-bin/faststream.jpg?stream=Full&amp;fps=0&quot;) 0% 0% / cover; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: black;">
    </div>
```

The image is of Type mjpg

Problem also is, I could not use "img" cause I need backgroundPosition at some of the images

Comment: can you share a code sample of your div? html and css at least. ideally what it looks like in the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix it by using a img tag in a div with overflow hidden.
So I could move the img in the div around.
And with img the stream stops when I set src to null